# Could not establish session to SSH gateway

Tags: python, network-programming, ssh-tunnel

I don't know where the issue is but when i start the server the error pops up.I even tried to change the `ip` addresses for the `ssh_address` but doesn't seem to work.I read on another question that it might be causing because of running it on pycharm(*in which the getpass doesn't responds and the code stops the execution right there*).

```
from getpass4 import getpass
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

ssh_host = "192.168.56.101"
ssh_port = 22
ssh_user = "xyx123"
ssh_password = getpass("Enter the password")

REMOTE_HOST = "192.168.56.101"
REMOTE_PORT = 21

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(ssh_address=(ssh_host, ssh_port),
                            ssh_username=ssh_user,
                            ssh_password=ssh_password,
                            remote_bind_address=(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT)
                            )

server.start()

print("Connect to remote server via local port: [%s]" % server.local_bind_port)
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting user request")
    server.stop()
```

**Terminal Errors:**

[image]

In short this code should get the the `local_bind_port` by which i can access it further on command prompt.